# Font-face with Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, font-face

Rails 3.2.3, sass.
I have placed the ttf, woff, eot, svg files in vendor/fonts folder.

I have also added this to application.rb :

```
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/fonts"
    config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I've created a file called fonts.css.scss in the vendor/stylesheets folder with the following code :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'museosans100';
src: font-url('/assets/museosans100.eot');
src: font-url('/assets/museosans100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     font-url('/assets/museosans100.woff') format('woff'),
     font-url('/assets/museosans100.ttf') format('truetype'),
     font-url('/assets/museosans100.svg#museosans100') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Then, I've used font-family : 'museosans100'; in the CSS bits.
The fonts still don't change. I've tried doing the same thing with the app/assets folder as well, but no use. What could I be missing? (I've tried restarting the server too.)

Comment: `I have placed the ttf, woff, eot, svg files in vendor/fonts folder.` Did you mean `vender/assets/fonts` here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'museosans100';
src: font-url('museosans100.eot');
src: font-url('museosans100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     font-url('museosans100.woff') format('woff'),
     font-url('museosans100.ttf') format('truetype'),
     font-url('museosans100.svg#museosans100') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```